# Memory leak in python 3 application after migration from python 2

Tags: python, python-3.x

Recently I have migrated a python 2 application to python 3. If I use python 3 interpreter, I notice memory leak. If I change the interpreter back to python 2, it work fine. I used futurize tool to make the code compatible with both python 2 and 3.

1. I used tracemalloc to see which line of code is allocating more memory.
2. gc module to get garbage collection stats etc.

But I could not find anything helpful. Has anything changed in py3 related to garbage collection? The application is a server which accepts telnet connection and process user input. hundreds of requests are coming every seconds. The number of objects keep growing in each iteration.

```
                    objects = gc.get_objects()
                    map_dict = defaultdict()
                    for o in objects:
                        count = map_dict.get(type(o).__name__, 0)
                        map_dict[type(o).__name__] = count + 1

                    LOG.info('=======>')
                    for k, v in map_dict.items():
                        if v > 1000:
                            LOG.info(k + " : " + str(v))
                    LOG.info(len(gc.get_objects()))
                    LOG.info(gc.get_stats())
                    LOG.info('<=======')


tuple : 6004
list : 4130
frame : 6196
builtin_function_or_method : 5973
dict : 8931
wrapper_descriptor : 1324
method_descriptor : 1173
getset_descriptor : 1667
weakref : 2996
function : 9918
type : 1612
set : 1097
method : 2143

62654
[{'collections': 65813, 'collected': 894, 'uncollectable': 0}, 
 {'collections': 5982, 'collected': 1117, 'uncollectable': 0}, 
 {'collections': 543, 'collected': 460, 'uncollectable': 0}]
```

Comment: We can't find anything as well. Mainly because you did not show us anything.

Comment: @KlausD. I have added more details. Let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).